# Javascript Cancel SetTimeout after button is clicked

Tags: javascript

There is an ok button and a cancel button

The code below will do this:

After I open dialog input , auto click the Cancel button after 10 seconds.

```
if(SceneManager._scene instanceof Scene_InputDialog) {
  setTimeout(function () {document.getElementById("inputDialog-CancelBtn").click();}, 10000);
}
```

If I click the ok button during those 10 seoconds , I will get this error below .( because after 10 seconds, it will try to auto click the cancel button which doesn't exist anymore; If Ok button is clicked, the cancel button will disappear)

Uncaught Type error: Cannot read propety 'click' of null

How should I clear the SetTimeout if the Ok button is clicked ?
Thanks in advance for any help

If I need to add reference to the OK button handler, how should I add it.
below is my other codes.

> okButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
>        okFunc();
>        e.preventDefault();
>      }, false);
>      cancelButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
>        cancelFunc();
>        e.preventDefault();
>      }, false);
>      okButton.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) {
>        okFunc();
>        e.preventDefault();
>      }, false);
>      cancelButton.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) {
>        cancelFunc();
>        e.preventDefault();
>      }, false);
>
> this._okFunc = okFunc;
>      this._cancelFunc = cancelFunc;
>    };

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Comment: [clearTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check if `document.getElementById("inputDialog-CancelBtn")` is not null before you `.click()`

```
if(SceneManager._scene instanceof Scene_InputDialog) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    const cancelBtn = document.getElementById("inputDialog-CancelBtn");
    if(cancelBtn) { 
      cancelBtn.click() 
    }
  }, 10000);
}
```

To clear the timeout the Ok button click handler needs to have a reference to the timeout, it's easier to just have that null check

Comment: Thanks I am new to Javascript.

Comment: I have updated the code, how do I add reference to the timeout ?

Comment: If you are doing the null check, you don't need to cancel the timeout.

Comment: if(SceneManager._scene instanceof Scene_InputDialog) {
  setTimeout(function ()if (document.getElementById("inputDialog-CancelBtn") !== null) if {document.getElementById("inputDialog-CancelBtn").click();}, 10000);
}

Comment: if(SceneManager._scene instanceof Scene_InputDialog) {
          setTimeout(function () {
            const cancelBtn = document.getElementById("inputDialog-CancelBtn");
            if(cancelBtn) { 
              cancelBtn.click() 
            }
          }, 10000);
    }

Comment: now it immediatly clicks the button. Not sure why but this link is the original whole script without adding my code. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/biud436/MV/master/RS_InputDialog.js

Comment: That shouldn't happen, maybe you didn't copy the code correctly. I've edited the answer and it contains the null-check. See if that's what you have

Comment: It was the – symbol at the end of the comment I accidentally copied, I removed it, now it works great! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

```
const myTimeout;

if(SceneManager._scene instanceof Scene_InputDialog) {
    myTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
      document.getElementById("inputDialog-CancelBtn").click();
  }, 10000);
}
```

then you can cancel it with:

```
clearTimeout(myTimeout)
```

Comment: Thanks, I am new to Javascript. I have updated the code, where should I add the clearTimeout(myTimeout)

Comment: in the OK button handler function

Comment: This is the link to the original whole script without adding my code, 
        https://raw.githubusercontent.com/biud436/MV/master/RS_InputDialog.js          I am not sure which one is the handler function, or where exactly should I put the clearTimeout(myTimeout)